# Sum list of values to a certain number and create the least number of "sets"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list with values that is variable in size and the individual values range from 1 to 33. (This is based on pallet amounts in trucks.)

I would like to select that range and have VBA code decide the best way to sum values to 33 (never over 33) and create an array with the values and move on to the next "set" and put the next values that add to 33 in a new array. I know how to do it chronically (thanks to a Stack Overflow user) but that isn't the most efficient option.

Let's say I have a list of 5 values:
10
15
8
22
19

this would create 3 "sets":
25
30
19

If the order of the 5 values changes to:
19
22
15
10
8

this would create 4 "sets":
19
22
15
18

I found a way to define a variable to the optimal number of trucks the code should create, but with the second list it would result in an error if the code goes through that list chronically.

Is it possible to create a code that would look at a selection of values and decide the most efficient way of combining values closest to 33.

```vb
Sub test()
Dim ref, b As Range
Dim volume, i As Integer
Dim test1(), check, total As Double
Dim c As Long

Set ref = Selection
volume = ref.Cells.Count
c = ref.Column
ReDim test1(1 To volume)

'this creates a total of all the values i select
For Each b In ref
    total = total + b
Next b

'this determines when to round up or down
check = total / 33 - Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(total / 33, 0)
If check < 0.6 Then
    total = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(total / 33, 0)
Else
    total = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(total / 33, 0)
End If

'this creates an array with all the values
i = 1
Do Until i = volume + 1
    test1(i) = Cells(i, c).Value
    i = i + 1
Loop

'this is just a way for me to check and verify my current part of the code
MsgBox (Round(test1(8), 2))
MsgBox (total)

End Sub
```

Comment: I dont understand how the examples you gave are related to the number 33. From left to right, you appear to be summing numbers whose sum is less than or equal to 33. But then in the second example you have `15 10 8` and don't sum 15 and 10, when by your rules you could sum 15 10 8 into 33. Can you clarify what rules you are using for creating the output?

Comment: This is the multiple subset sum problem, there is no known algorithm to do this efficiently.

Comment: `i = 1`: `Do Until i = volume + 1` and `i = i + 1` Welcome to VBA, I would like to introduce you to the amazing [For Loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement). You can write your loop in one neat line `For i = 1 To volume + 1`

Comment: @Toddleson you are right, bad example from my side. but why i am so set on the 33 is that i is the max amount of pallets that fit in a truck, i want my code to be able to "form" the least amount possible of full trucks when i run the macro. thats why the number 33 is so important. the examples i used athough poorly are dummy values for pallet amounts. the rules i look for is that out of a variable range the code needs to create the least amount of full trucks ( full truck is 33). so lets say 20 values add up to 180, than the code needs to create 5 full trucks.

Comment: @Toddleson thanks for the for loop tip :) im still in the process of learning to code efficiently

Comment: @Warcupine i googled what you mentioned and it sure looks like that, at this point i'll take not efficiently over not at all :) you think there is a way to do it in VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a straight brute force, checking every single combination, if your set gets too big this will slow way down but it was <1 second on a set of 1,000.

I loaded values into Column A. Outputs the lowest amount of trucks you need.

You can probably reduce the amount of variables by using a type or class but wanted to keep it relatively simple.

```
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim limit As Long
    Dim count As Long
    Dim sets As Long
    Dim best As Long
    Dim start As Long
    Dim addset As Boolean
    Dim loopcounter As Long
    
    limit = 33
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim arr() As Long
        ReDim arr(0 To lr - 2)
        For i = 2 To lr
            arr(i - 2) = .Cells(i, 1).Value 'Load array
        Next i
        
        start = 0
        i = start
        Do
            If count + arr(i) <= limit Then
                count = count + arr(i)
                addset = False 'Just for tracking the final set
            Else
                addset = True
                sets = sets + 1
                count = arr(i)
            End If
            i = i + 1
            If i > UBound(arr) Then
                i = 0 'reset index
            End If
            loopcounter = loopcounter + 1 'tracking items in set
            If loopcounter > UBound(arr) Then
                If addset = False Then
                    sets = sets + 1 'adding final set if not already added
                End If
                Debug.Print start, sets
                If best > sets Or best = 0 Then
                    best = sets 'Get the lowest value
                End If
                'resetting values
                loopcounter = 0
                sets = 0
                start = start + 1
                i = start
                If start > UBound(arr) Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
            End If
        Loop
    End With
    Debug.Print best
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the cell result location as per your wish. I am showing the result in the immediate window.

```
Sub test()
Dim CellsCount As Integer

CellsCount = Selection.Cells.Count

Dim i, j As Long
Dim x, y As Long
Dim SumLoop As Long
SumLoop = 0
x = 1
y = 1

For i = x To CellsCount
    Do
        For j = y To CellsCount
            SumLoop = SumLoop + Selection.Cells(j).Value
            If SumLoop < 33 Then
                Debug.Print SumLoop
                y = j + 1
                If y = CellsCount + 1 Then Exit Sub
            Else
                
                SumLoop = 0
                x = j
                y = j
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Loop While SumLoop < 33
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: while im definetly thankfull for this code because i can use it somewhere else. this code only goes through a list in order. so in my 2 example the first time it creates 3 sums and in the second example it creates 4. so for me it doesnt produce the result i want sadly:(

Comment: This should work for your 2nd example also. For 2nd results, output will be 4.  I have tried myself... This will sum up to meet 33.

Comment: Another way is you can apply excel formula which will be very clean, easy, speediest way ...

Comment: it creates 4 yes, thats why its not suitable. because i need the code to create the least amount of sets of <33 possible out of any selected range. if you go through any range by order it will never look at the most optimal combination of all the data. but im starting to think  what i want is not at all possible in VBA. im just going to use your part of code and loop all my "left overs" back over the created sets, that should somewhat be in the ballpark of what i want :) many thanks for your code